# Has John Huber interviewed any witnesses in his review?

Tags: united-states, law, mueller-investigation

In 2017, after the appointment of Special Counsel Robert Muller to oversee the FBI’s Trump-Russia investigation.

Congressional Republicans asked the Department of Justice to appoint a second Special Counsel to investigate other matters they wanted investigated, like the Clinton Foundation, Uranium One, and FISA abuse. Then-Attorney General Jeff Sessions refused, but he [tasked John Huber, U.S. Attorney for the District of Utah](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/03/29/politics/sessions-prosecutor-fbi-misconduct-clinton-uranium-one-special-counsel/index.html), with reviewing some of these matters and making recommendations as to whether any new investigations needed to be opened or any new Special Counsels needed to be appointed.

I discuss the exact scope of Huber’s review in my answer [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/39351/1953).  But now I’m wondering what Huber has done so far in his review.  The review is still ongoing, but my question is, have any witnesses been interviewed in connection to Huber’s review?  In other cases, like the Trump-Russia investigation, people who were interviewed by Mueller’s team have told the press about it.  Has the same happened in this case?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not included in the public record up to earlier this month (April 2019). The Spectator USA had [an article on this](https://spectator.us/waiting-huber-investigation-fbi-abuse/) titled *Waiting for Huber: whatever happened to the investigation into FBI abuse of power?*

They wrote:

> Members of Congress remain in the dark about what if any progress has been made, and likely witnesses say they haven’t been contacted.
>
> [...]
>
> Huber’s office has maintained its total silence even as President Trump and other Republicans’ demands for an investigation become more strident
>
> [...]
>
> The Spectator USA asked the Department of Justice whether they could provide an update on what work counsel has undertaken, if they have contacted any members of Congress or responded to their requests, and what has been done in the last 18 months. Spokesperson Wyn Hornbuckle responded only, ‘we have no updates at this time.’